# MongoDB Query generating same result set for multiple pages

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Sample Data in mongodb collection attached as image.

[image]

Query with sort and limit.

Same Data Getting populated in multiple result set.

```
Page 1 ->Query
db.user_profile.find({},{ email: 1}).skip(0).limit(3).sort( {isEnabled:-1,firstName:1} )
Page 2 ->Query
db.user_profile.find({},{ email: 1}).skip(3).limit(3).sort( {isEnabled:-1,firstName:1} )
Page 3 ->Query
db.user_profile.find({},{ email: 1}).skip(6).limit(3).sort( {isEnabled:-1,firstName:1} )
```

[image]

Comment: Please look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38050779/mongodb-sort-with-skip-and-limit-not-sort-the-record-according-to-index. `$sort` should be before `$skip`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongodb sort with skip and limit not sort the record according to index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38050779/mongodb-sort-with-skip-and-limit-not-sort-the-record-according-to-index)

Comment: @nimrodserok  no after updating query it is not working. When I sort int or date it works well. But for String it is not working.

Comment: `isEnabled` is not on the schema that you provided. Is this by mistake?

Comment: @nimrodserok
Yes there is one more field isEnabled . and it is boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to project what you are sorting. One way to do it is:

```
db.user_profile.find({},{ email: 1, isEnabled: 1, firstName:1}).skip(3).limit(3).sort( {isEnabled:-1,firstName:1} )
```

Notice the projection of `isEnabled` and `firstName` that were missing before. This is a simple query but will result in adding two more fields to the output.

If you want to return **only** the `email`, you can use an aggregation pipeline that will remove the projection on a latter stage:

```
db.user_profile.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {isEnabled: -1, firstName: 1}
  },
  {$skip: 0},
  {$limit: 3},
  {$project: {email: 1}} // or {$project: {email: 1, _id: 0}}
])
```

You can see the aggregation example working on the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4TqfafRW46R)

Comment: yes I did this , still not working

Comment: https://ibb.co/F5Vz6qG 
Query

Comment: In your picture you are sorting by first name, and the arrows shows the email. You are not sorting by email